# Tasks will not run in Spring Cloud Data Flow (Docker/K8S)

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

Last week I installed the Docker/Kubernetes based version of Spring Cloud Data Flow

Although there were not overt errors, things are not working correctly.

I am able to create streams and tasks in the web UI and Spring Cloud Data Flow Shell but nothing runs.

I am most interested in Tasks.

When I create them, they all show with a Task Status of UNKNOWN.

Unfortunately, no matter how many times I launch them, the status always remains UNKNOWN.

I'm able to delete them but what magic must I use to make them run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a misconfiguration on my end.

I'm able to run as expected now.

Comment: I am also facing same issue. could you please mention what is exact issue.

Comment: this question was 2 years ago for a company i'm no longer with.  i have no recollection of the problem nor do i have any way of looking up the solution.  Given my response, I'd double check all the configuration.  Perhaps examining the logs/output as suggested by Sabby Anandan will provide extra information.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing apparent from the description as to what has failed. Perhaps if you can update it with more details, it'd be useful.

From a troubleshooting standpoint, when deploying streams or if the launch of Tasks' fails for any reason, they will be logged in the SCDF-server/Skipper-server logs. You'd have to tail the logs of the respective pod to learn more about the failures.

Also, it'd be useful to verify the output of `kubectl describe pod/<POD_NAME>` to see what's causing the stream/task pods not to start successfully. They're usually listed towards the end of this command-output.

The usual suspects are due to pods' health-check failures and/or the stream/task application docker images aren't resolvable at runtime. You'll see the reasons in the logs, of course.